# Androidx and YouTubePlayerSupportFragment

Tags: java, android-studio, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

Good day,

I'm sorry if I may come off as ignorant but i have an error and I'm not sure of the cause. I tried using the YoutubePlayerSupportFragment. My main activity extends AppCompatActivity and I'm using androidx, not the support library. My error is seen in the compiler but doesn't affect the the apps compilation at all.

the error is displayed as:

> inconvertible types; cannot cast 'androidx.fragment.app.Fragment' to
>   'com.google.android.youtube.player.YoutubePlayerSupportFragment'

[image]

and my code samples are

```
YouTubePlayerSupportFragment youTubePlayerFragment = (YouTubePlayerSupportFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.youtube_player);
```

and

```
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:name="com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerSupportFragment"
    android:id="@+id/youtube_player"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
```

As said before the app runs and the Youtube player works, but i know that the error should not be there. Am I casting incorrectly?

Comment: YouTubePlayerSupportFragment is a sub class of android.support.v4.app.Fragment which means the fragment is not yet migrated to AndroidX